# User authentication on C#

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth

I'm trying to create a client-server application, with authentication through Office 365. I`ve chosen this way: client send login/password to server and server just check if they are correct.

I dont know how to create such checking of login/password. 
I have found some OAuth samples, but they are all about authentication in apps, created for services like Twitter,Facebook etc. This is the way they are obtain consumer key and secret.

I have aslo found how to sign in programmicaly with help of PowerShell or WebClient class, but that is just signing in, how would i know in login/password are correct?

Maybe those are very close to what i want to do, but i can not change and tie them to my programm. Please, help me with that.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm not sure what you are asking...

Comment: OAuth is used to make custom application authorized to access protected resource (like FB photos) from behalf of user.

Answer (score 0):

What's your goal? To build an app that works with Office 365 assets? If yes, look for Apps for SharePoint. If no, then look for Windows Azure Directory Services and Access Control Services—that's the authentication and user management engine behind Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solutions:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx

http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/03/24/sharepoint-online-web-service-authentication-using-wcf-client-side-behaviour/